# dpkg error code (1)

Tags: dpkg, jdk

I got this error code while installing JDK 9 on my ubuntu 16.04 machine :

```
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
/var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Which means : `errors been faced when executing /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb` ..

Any help please ?

Comment: That is not the actual error, just a summary. The real error message was displayed earlier. Install the package again and look for the actual error.

Comment: Yes, you need to give the command you are running, and the entire output.

Comment: maybe this one is the actual error : dpkg: erreur de traitement de l'archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b114-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack) :
 tentative de remplacement de « /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/jawt_md.h », qui appartient aussi au paquet openjdk-9-jdk-headless:amd64 9~b114-0ubuntu1

Comment: the command is : apt-get install openjdk-9-jdk

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=820023

There is a conflict between `openjdk-9-jdk` and `openjdk-9-jdk-headless` which ought to be resolved by the package management software, but isn't. They try to write the same file. The error message in English is:

```
Unpacking openjdk-9-jdk:amd64 (9~b112-2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/openjdk-9-jdk_9~b112-2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/include/linux/jawt_md.h', which is also in package openjdk-9-jdk-headless:amd64 9~b112-2
```

However, there is an easy solution: remove the package `openjdk-9-jdk-headless` first:

```
sudo apt-get remove openjdk-9-jdk-headless
```

because there is no sense in keeping both of these packages.

Comment: I tried to do a manual installation to jdk8 and it worked fine but thank u any way

Comment: Same here. Moved to jdk8 instead of jdk9

Comment: No, it doesn't work, when you do `apt install openjdk-9-jdk` it will try to install `openjdk-9-jdk-headless` anyway.